# lapply of list in ReporteRs packages

Tags: r, loops, lapply, reporters

I have a list of names and list of table which create in `ReporteRs` packages, called "MyFTable", I tried to apply list of MyFTable with list of t

```
t1 <- c("a","b","c")
t2 <- c("d","e","f")
t <- list(t1, t2)
```

If I do separately, it works, but when I put in the loop, it doesn't work.

```
  addHeaderRow(MyFTable[[1]], value=c("", t1))
  addHeaderRow(MyFTable[[2]], value=c("", t2))
```

This is my attempt:

```
  for(i in 1: length(MyFTable)){
  lapply(MyFTable[[i]],function(x) addHeaderRow(x, value=c("",t[[i]])))
}

for(i in 1: length(MyFTable)){
  lapply(MyFTable[[i]],function(x) addHeaderRow(x[[i]], value=c("",t[[i]])))
}
```

I got error :

> x must be a FlexTable

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Why are you `lapply`ing _in_ a `for`-loop? Use one or the other, and if you're going to use `for`-loops, preallocate.

Comment: I tried to apply the first list of df with the first list of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `lapply` for no good reason. You can do that in a regular loop.

```
out <- vector("list", length(MyFTable)) # always pre-allocate

for(i in 1:length(MyFTable)){
  out[[i]] <- addHeaderRow(MyFTable[[i]], value=c("",t[[i]])))
}
```

You can also use `mapply` which works on corresponding elements from all provided objects (in this case `mft` and `tt`).

```
myFun <- function(mft, tt) addHeaderRow(mft, tt)
mapply(FUN = myFun, mft = MyFTable, tt = t)
```

If you are hell-bent on `lapply`, you could "hide a loop".

```
lapply(1:length(MyFTable), FUN = function(i, mft, tt) {
  addHeaderRow(mft[[i]], value = c("", tt[[i]]))
}, mft = MyFTable, tt = t)
```

This last piece of code is interesting because it's easy to show how debugging works in R. By setting `browser()` at some point in a function, the execution will stop at that point and you can either inspect elements or advance by typing `n` or `c`. First command will move one line forward (from `browser()` call) and `c` will execute the current "loop" and wait at the `browser()` line in the next loop (if not finished, then it exists).

Try it, execute

```
lapply(1:length(MyFTable), FUN = function(i, mft, tt) {
  browser()
  addHeaderRow(mft[[i]], value = c("", tt[[i]]))
}, mft = MyFTable, tt = t)
```

and your prompt should change a bit. Inspect elements `i`, `mft` and `tt` and see if they match your `MyFTable[[1]]` and `t[[1]]` elements. To quit, type `Q`.

Comment: So if I have another function MyFTable[1,1:10, newpar=TRUE, to="header"]<- c("", second[[i]]) How it works for apply your function()

Comment: I try for(i in 1:length(MyFTable)){MyFTable[[i]][1,1:10, newpar=TRUE, to="header"]<- c("", second[[i]])} it works

Comment: @Stat at this point I will ask you to make a new question and provide a reproducible example. [Here are some tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do just that.

Comment: I will take a look into that, thanks for your advance